# Virtualhost setup, same IP address, different DirectoryIndex's

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am trying to set up 2 virtual host entries in apache but I'm not sure how to accomplish what I want to do.  I have two domain names, both pointing to the same IP Address. I need the `DirectoryIndex` to be different, which is pretty much the only difference in the entries.  I have the following set up:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName firstdomain.com
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www"
    DirectoryIndex  /portals/site/index.html

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName seconddomain.com
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www"
    DirectoryIndex  /portals/site/index_fr.html

</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure what I need to do differently but the second entry doesn't work. The only real difference is I need the second domain to point to a different `DirectoryIndex`.  If there is a better way to accomplish this, your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [`NameVirtualHost *:80`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) somewhere before the `VirtualHost`
sections in your configuration. Otherwise, your `VirtualHost` sections are
treated as IP-based virtual hosts, and as you correctly have observed, the
second entry is essentially getting ignored.

You may want to read up on [name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).